# No member named '' in ''. Why did it happen and how do I fix it?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have an error when I print my PrintSount() in the main. The compiler said:

> No member named 'PrintSound' in 'animal')

Why is this happening and how I can fix it?

#### main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "animal.h"
#include "pat.h"
#include "not_pat.h"

int main()
{
    std::string lastName;
    std::string sound;
    std::string name;
    std::string type;
    double speed = 0;

    animal* animals[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        std::string ani;

        std::cout << "Enter animal: (dog,fish,lion,monkey ... ): " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> ani;

        if (ani == "dog" || ani == "cat" || ani == "fish")
        {
            animals[i] = new pat("test", "test", "test","test");
        }
        else
        {
            animals[i] = new not_pat(speed,  lastName, "test2",  "test2");
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        std::cout << animals[i]->PrintName() << animals[i]->PrintLatName() << animals[i]-    >PrintType() << animals[i]->PrintSound() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

#### animal.h

```
#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#define ANIMAL_H

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

class animal{

    public:

        animal(std::string name, std::string type, std::string lastName);
        std::string PrintType();
        std::string PrintName();
        std::string PrintLatName();

    protected:

        std::string _name;
        std::string _lastName;
        std::string _type;

    private:



};

#endif
```

#### animal.cpp

```
#include "animal.h"

animal::animal(std::string name , std::string type, std::string lastName)
{
    _name = name;
    _type = type;
    _lastName = lastName;
}

std::string animal::PrintType()
{
    return this->_type;
}

std::string animal::PrintName()
{
    return this->_name;
}

std::string animal::PrintLatName()
{
    if(_lastName == "0")
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        return this->_lastName;
    }
}
```

#### pat.h

```
#ifndef PAT_H
#define PAT_H

#include "animal.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

class pat : public animal
{

    public:

        pat(std::string lastName, std::string sound, std::string name, std::string type);
        std::string PrintSoud(animal *p);

    protected:

        std::string _sound;

    private:

};

#endif
```

#### pat.cpp

```
#include "pat.h"
#include "animal.h"

pat::pat(std::string lastName, std::string sound, std::string name, std::string type) :     animal(name,type,lastName)
{
    _sound = sound;
}

std::string pat::PrintSoud(animal *p)
{
    return this->_sound;
}
```

#### not_pat.h

```
#ifndef NOT_PAT_H
#define NOT_PAT_H

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

class not_pat : public animal
{
    public:

        not_pat(double speed,std::string lastName, std::string name, std::string type);
        double PrintSpeed();

    protected:

    double _speed;

    private:

};

#endif
```

#### not_pat.cpp

```
#include "animal.h"
#include "not_pat.h"

not_pat::not_pat(double speed, std::string lastName, std::string name, std::string type) : animal(name, type,lastName)
{
    if(speed == 0)
    {
        _speed = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        _speed = speed;
    }
}

double not_pat::PrintSpeed()
{
    return this->_speed;
}
```

Comment: Did you actually read the error?

Answer (score 1):

C++ is a statically-typed language. You use `pat` using a pointer to `animal`. So the compiler checks if `animal` has the member function `PrintSound()`. It does not have it, so there is a compilation error raised. You need to add the declaration of `PrintSound` to `animal` (probably a pure virtual function) to fix this.

Comment: Yes I did it but now when I set a new animal is say thet (Allocating an object of abstract class type 'pat') and it does not work

Comment: you need to implement all pure virtual functions in pat